# css grid full screen with margin/padding

Tags: css, margin, fullscreen, css-grid

With CSS Grid, I need a full screen with fixed header, nav and footer, only article is flex.

[`With margin = 0px it is OK`](https://codepen.io/ariebl/pen/YvrPrV)

But with margin = 10px its not ok [`since footer is not fixed below`](https://codepen.io/ariebl/pen/NzaPwO)

How can I keep full screen with fixed header, nav and footer (only article is flex) also with margin = 20px?

Comment: Can you provide an example like a snippet or improve your question? It's way too broad.

Comment: I have now corrected the links in the question

Comment: Please define "OK". What do you mean by "height is larger" ?

Comment: Write some code please

Comment: Link to codepen.io without explanation won't help us to help you. Your question will just be removed.

Comment: I corrected my question, hope it will be better understood and thanks for the feedback even it was nerative its help me...

Comment: No, your question is not good. Please read how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for `box-sizing`.
By default `box-sizing` of `body` is set to `content-box` – which means:

> The width and **height** properties include the content, but does not include the padding, border, or margin.

`height` property of body in your case is `100vh`, but when you set `margin` – it takes `100vh + 2 * 20px`, which is *more* than `100vh`.

To prevent this you have to take `margin` into account – set `height: calc(100vh - 40px);` on body:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "nav article article"
    "nav footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

header,
footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
  background-color: #379;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
@media all and (max-width: 975px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "nav"
      "article"
      "article"
      "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
<footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

So your question basically is why the body occupies more space when you add a margin or padding?

It's common sense that if you add something to an element like margin or padding, that element to occupy more space  to increase by default.

Please take a look at CSS box model. Read here -> [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) or here [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

> Important: When you set the width and height properties of an element with CSS, you just set the width and height of the content area. To calculate the full size of an element, you must also add padding, borders and margins.

To have `height:100vh` together with `margin:20px` you need to substract that margin from the `100vh` with `calc()`. So the code would be `body { height: calc(100vh - 40px)}` . You substract `40px` because `margin:20px` is equal to `margin-top:20px;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:20px` So you have `top-bottom : 20+20 = 40px`margin.

For the padding you can use `box-sizing:border-box` -> more here [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> border-box    The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border

```css
body {
margin:20px;
height:calc(100vh - 40px);
padding:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
background:red;
}
```